# Profiling org-mode init file

Tags: org-mode, init-file, performance, profiler, benchmarking

My initialization file is organized in `org-mode` with src snippets. Is there a way I can profile it to see which snippets take the most time to evaluate? When my initialization file was in Elisp, I was able to profile it with [ProfileDotEmacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ProfileDotEmacs), but that doesn't work for me anymore.

Here is how I load the Org file:

```
(org-babel-load-file "path/to/main.org")
```

Since the snippets are evaluated with Babel, maybe there's a way to tell Babel to output the execution time of each snippet?

Comment: Use `M-x org-babel-tangle` to produce the pure elisp file and profile that one instead.

Comment: `org-babel-load-file` should tangle the file already. Try the profiledotemacs on `"path/to/main.el"`. This file should exist ones you have loaded your initial file.